# How to get Xcode 6 to regenerate provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm a new iOS developer and I am having a strange problem with my Xcode-generated provisioning profile. I am the only developer on my team (and in my company) and yet the provisioning profile shows 50 certificates. I only have one development certificate and am the only person developing. I only use one Mac and one Mac server. I'm not sure how this happened. I guess I can't post an image here yet, but on Member Center, when clicking on the iOSTeam Provisioning Profile it shows:

- Name:iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *
- Type:iOS DevelopmentApp ID:
- Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID (*)
- ***Certificates: 50 total***
- Devices: 5 total
- Enabled Services: None
- Expires:Jan 02, 2016
- Status:Active (Managed by Xcode)

I've searched here and elsewhere on the web and tried many ways to get Xcode to simply create a new provisioning profile, but it always seems to just recreate one with 50 certificates. I've tried:

- Deleting all provisioning profiles from Xcode
- Signing out my developer account in Xcode
- Deleting all provisioning profiles on member center
- Restarting Xcode

At this point, Xcode just recreates the iOSTeam Provisioning Profile with 50 certificates.

I have also revoked my development certificate, created a new one, and had Xcode recreate the provisioning profile. Same thing happened.

I have created my own provisioning profile and that one is correct. But, I'd like to have Xcode manage all this so would prefer to use that one.

I've talked to Apple, and they don't know what happened, but don't think there is really an issue since this profile is working OK. They said to just keep using this one. But, I guess I'm neurotic and would like a correct profile.

I guess I really have two questions:

- Has anyone ever seen this and if so, do you know what causes it (and how to fix it)?
- Has anyone figured out how to get Xcode to truly re-create a provisioning profile from scratch?

I appreciate any insight and help.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone figured out how to get Xcode to truly re-create a provisioning profile from scratch

Yes, but it's not easy. You have to delete *everything* related to certificates and provisioning profiles, both on your computer(s) and at the Member Center.

- So, first you quit Xcode and restart the computer so that nothing is cached.
- Now delete all caches associated with Xcode, as I explain here: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)
- Delete the contents of *~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles*.
- Use Keychain Access to delete your identities and certificates.
- Do the above on every machine you develop on!
- Go to the Member Center and revoke/delete absolute everything, one by one. This can be a long process. You won't be able to delete distribution certificates for apps already on the app store, but everything else you will be able to remove.
- Just to be on the safe side, go to every device and delete any profiles (General settings).

You can now begin the process of requesting a development certificate. I always do this manually, generating the request from Keychain Access and uploading it to the Member Center. When you've downloaded and installed the certificate in the keychain, launch Xcode and attach a device and ask to use it for development. You will end up with a new team profile. I hope.

Comment: I tried all of your steps, but unfortunately, I still get a Provisioning Profile that shows 51 certificates (up from 50!). I supposed I can just let this go as it all seems to work OK. I guess I'm just worried that at some point this will bite me. (BTW, I really appreciate your help)

Comment: Hey, 51. That could be a record! - I've never seen this 50-certificate thing, so I was just giving the best advice I had. I went through that process recently when Swift stopped working (I couldn't run any Swift apps on a device), and I go through it every year when my certificates expire, so I was hoping it would help. I'm sorry it didn't.

Comment: These instructions helped me with my problem. I had switched my dev account and Xcode was using some thin air certificate and provisioning profile of the old account, even though I wiped `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and deleted everything from the member center of my old account. After going though those steps, Xcode generated both new and now they show up in the member center with my new developer account. Thanks!